Querying for a JSON object in AWS cloudsearch literal field
I'm currently working on implementing search functionality using Amazon CloudSearch and encountering an issue with filtering documents based on partner authorization levels. I have a CloudSearch domain containing documents with various fields, including one called partner_types_authorization_level, which stores JSON data representing authorization levels for different partner types.
Here's a simplified example of the structure of my documents:
{
  "org_id": "123456",
  "company_name": "Example Corp",
  "partner_types_authorization_level": [
    {"CSP": "AUTHORIZED"},
    {"CSN": "SILVER"}
]
}

I need to construct a query that filters documents based on the partner_types_authorization_level field. Specifically, I want to retrieve documents where {"CSN": "SILVER"}.  But there is a chance that documents with {"CSN": "SILVER"} and other combinations like {"CSN": "GOLD"} etc. I only want the documents with {"CSN": "SILVER"}
Here's the query I've attempted to use:
(and country_code:'US' (or (term field=partner_types_authorization_level '{"CSN":"SILVER"}') ))

Here I am getting records where it matches CSN only or just SILVER only and not exact {"CSN": "SILVER"}. The data type for this field is literal. I tried with text,text-array etc but not working.  Could anyone help me understand what might be wrong with my query or suggest a better approach to achieve this filtering requirement in Amazon CloudSearch?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
